# Issues while configuring spark on scala eclipse IDE

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

When I am configuring spark environment in Scala Eclipse. I am not able to use this import

```
import org.apache.spark (showing error cant find spark)
```

I have tried multiple jars and diff combinations can anyone please let me know how to proceed. I can't find appropriate Jar for this as I am stuck in this for `org.apache.spark`.

I tried adding jars from `usr/lib/spark/lib`, but didn't work.

Can anyone tell me which jars I need to import for this and where to find them as I am using top-gear hadoop-cloudera environment.

Comment: you will nedd spark-core and spark-sql jars. Is your project a maven or sbt ? You can find more information to include in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark

Comment: If you're writing code inside the quickstart VM, then that's the correct location to get jar files from. So, did you add the whole folder, or only some jars? However, in production, you should really be using Maven/Gradle/SBT